# nodejs encryption data using mongoose-encryption

Tags: node.js, mongoose, encryption

I am trying to use mongoose-encryption with nodejs to encrypt new users' password, but I am getting the error

```
"C:\Users\user\OneDrive\old Desktop\web developer\WebDevelopment\Secrets - Starting Code\node_modules\mongoose-encrypt\lib\index.js:123
    paths.forEach(function(path) {^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"
```

this is the code for the encryption:

```
const usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

const secret = "Thisisourlittilesecret";
usersSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret, encryptedFields: ['password'] });

const User = mongoose.model("User", usersSchema);
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of your code? (Including the part where you call forEach)

Comment: Actually, I did not use it. it seems to be inside of the mongoose-encryption model's file

Comment: The problem is in `node_modules` folder, so it's definitely mongoose-encryption source code's error.
To be specific it's in this file: `\node_modules\mongoose-encrypt\lib\index.js`.

But I think that it's caused by `encrypt` variable.
Have you added this:

`const encrypt = require('mongoose-encryption');`

and this:

`const mongoose = require('mongoose');`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue

Turns out I imported 'mongoose-encrypt' instead of 'mongoose-encryption'